# protractor : unable to click the button

Tags: protractor

Im new to protractor e2e testing.
Writing jasmine test cases using protractor.
I have two buttons in a html file. I want to select the specific button(button in begin.html file)

These did not work

`element(by.id('gotest')).click();`

`by.linkUiSref('about-you');`

performing some event on the button should navigate to next page(about-you)

Please help me

**Text.html**

```
<div class="button">
    <a ui-sref="begin">
        <button class="green">Text</button>
    </a>
</div>

<ng-include src="'../begin.html'" class="hidden"></ng-include>
```

**begin.html**

```
<div class="button">
    <button class="green" id="gotest" ui-sref="about-you">Start</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm assuming you're on begin.html when you tried to click right? (i.e. not sure what Text.html has to do with this). Also, what do you mean by "did not work"? Did nothing happen or did it error out?

Comment: yes you are correct im on begin.html(click event happens here).

Comment: yes you are correct im on begin.html(click event happens here).when we launch the application in mobile, text.html will be displayed first ,then begin.html. But we access the same application in desktop begin.html will be included in text.html. Im getting the below exception "essage:
 Error: Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 11 seconds.
aq.md......" I also tried using allscriptsTimeouts in config file, but it did not worked.

Comment: Is your app an Angular app? If not you will need to add this "browser.ignoreSynchronization = true" in the beginning, then set "browser.ignoreSynchronization = false" once your app becomes angular.

Comment: yes our application is angular.

Comment: In config file i have given allscripts=100000 ms , so now im not getting timeout not synchronized after 11 sec error , but i see a different error "A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow The last active task was: Protractor.waitForAngular() at [object Object].webdriver.WebDriver.schedule (C:\Users\pm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\ iver\webdriver.js:345:15) at [object Object].Protractor.executeAsyncScript_ (C:\Users\pm\node_modules\protractor\lib\protractor.js:1141:26)

Comment: It still looks like some kind of synchronization problem (maybe there's a setTimeout() in your app if you think protractor is bootstrapping properly).

Answer (score 7):

Protractor works fast and asynchronous. So, your button click might just be executed even before the page is ready and hence you get errors. To resolve this issue you can first try to find the element using wait function in protractor and then using the promise that the wait returns, you can click on the button.

Below code might help you -

```
var elementToClick = $('#gotest');
browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(elementToClick), 10000)
.then ( function () {
    elementToClick.click();
});
```

Hope this solved your problem.

Answer (score 5):

**Try:**

```
element(by.buttonText('Start')).click();
```

**otherwise please send what error you have got.**

Comment: Thanks for your reply, in config file i have given allscripts=100000 ms , so now im not getting timeout after 11 sec error , but i see a different error "A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow
The last active task was:
Protractor.waitForAngular()
    at [object Object].webdriver.WebDriver.schedule (C:\Users\pm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\
iver\webdriver.js:345:15)
    at [object Object].Protractor.executeAsyncScript_ (C:\Users\pm\node_modules\protractor\lib\protractor.js:1141:26)
    at [object Object].Protractor.waitForAngula

Comment: also im getting my element the way you mentioned above.

Comment: if you want to get timeout error after 11sec, you must set the allscripts=10000ms in config file, not 100000ms

Comment: sorry for many comments, as this is my first post i could not explain in clear way. I dont want  time out error...my script should fire a click event, so that it navigates to next page. First test is not executing. iit('Hello',function(){
     element(by.buttonText('Start')).click();
      
   });

  iit('second page test.', function() {
    
    element(by.id('firstName')).sendKeys('test');
    
});

Comment: why are you say sorry, nothing happen, be coooool, do good coding.