# How to locate a button in protractor as span

Tags: javascript, protractor

I have a button in my application, below mentioned is the HTML.

```
<button _ngcontent-c5 class="btn qf-btn" disabled>
<span _ngcontent-c5>ADD CUSTOMER</span>
</button>
```

I need to figure out how to locate the "ADD CUSTOMER" button using protractor. I am not able to locate it using by.buttonText.

Comment: bit more clear?

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27955231/protractor-unable-to-click-the-button You can select the button using `$('.qf-btn')`, I believe

Answer (score 1):

You can't locate it using by.buttonText because this text not in the `<button>` tag, but in the `<span>`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try locate button using partial matching with `class`.

```
const button = $('[class~="qf-btn"]');
await button.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Interact with the span inside the button like this `element(by.cssContainingText("span", "ADD CUSTOMER"));`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('span')
```

This should do the trick. However, I'd advise you to chain the elements.

```
let elName = $('.parentCssClass span')
elName.click();
```